# mysql to syslog

Tags: mysql, syslog

I would like to log information on mysql database performances (tables spaces, number of queries...) in a file and then forward to a syslog remote server. Mysql is installed
on Linux. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating a log file for example: 
% sudo touch filename.log

Setting owner/group 
% sudo chown mysql:wheel filename.log

Setting permissions to -rw-r----- 
% sudo chmod 644 filename.log

To log queries taking longer than 2 seconds to a log file in /var/log directory add these to the my.cnf file:

[mysqld]
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql_slow_query.log
long_query_time=2